# "bpl" load in IntraWeb

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I am setting up a module of "bpl" load in IntraWeb, Delphi2010, and I found the following problem:
I don't get to create an instance the application to not to be this is as an internal form.
.

```
procedure CargaDoSubModulo;
type
  TIWFormClass = class of TIWForm;

var
  Integra : IIntegracaoIW;
  Formulario : TIWForm;
  intClas : Integer;
  strForm : String;

begin
  strForm := srtPacotes + '_' + Copy ( IntToStr ( Rtn_Alternativa)  + 10000 ), 2, 4 );

// Descrição do formulário
  strDescricaoTela := Des_Tela;
// Nome da classe do formulário
  vrtClasseModulo := 'p_' + strForm + '.dll';

// Nome da rotina interna a ser carregada
  strForm := 'iwfrm_' + strForm;
// Nome da classe do formulário
  vrtNomeFormulario := 'T'    + strForm;
// Verificação se a rotina e compativel com o sistema iwfrm_hrb_0010
  intClas := -1;

  if WebApplication.FindComponent( strForm ) = nil then
  begin
     Formulario := TIWFormClass(FindClass( vrtNomeFormulario )).Create(WebApplication);

     if not Supports (Formulario, IIntegracaoIW) then
     begin
        WebApplication.ShowMessage(CargaTexto(msnRotIncompIntgra), smAlert);
        Exit;
     end;

     Integra := Formulario as IIntegracaoIW;
     with Integra do
     begin
        SetServidor( ParServidor1.Servidor );                             // 1
        SetAreaTrabalho( ParServidor1.AreaTrabalho );                     // 2
        SetIdUsuario( intUsuario );                                       // 3
        SetNomeUsuario( iwlStUsuario.Caption );                           // 11
        SetAcesso( intAcesso );                                           // 4
        SetEmpresa( ParServidor1.Empresa );                               // 5
        SetFilial( ParServidor1.Filial );                                 // 6
        SetIdClasse( intClas );                                           // 8
        SetVersao( strVersaoInterna );                                    // 10
        SetDescricao(Des_Tela );     // 7
        SetEnderecoIP( strIdentificacaoPorta );                           // 13
        SetDataTrabalho( DateToStr(dtDataTrabalho) );                     // 14
        SetIdentificacaoSistema( iwlIdentificacao.Caption );              // 12
        SetModuloCarga(Rtn_Busca ); // 9
     end;
  end;
  TIWAppForm(WebApplication.FindComponent( strForm )).Show;
```

end;

Comment: I've tried to improve your code formatting, but I still don't understand your question.  Could you edit it to make it more clear what you are trying to do, and include any error messages you are getting?  Falo português só um pouquinho.

Comment: Well...  
I am setting up a selector of modules...  
The main module is a Dll and the secondary modules are Bpl, that are loaded from within of the selector (Dll), or be:  
1st set up the name of the module in vrtClasseModulo;  
2nd set up the name of the form of the module in vrtNomeFormulario, that is the Class;  
3rd verify if she exists; and  
4th to initialize and I present to form.  
  
It is that that I want do....  
  
It was worth the help... and I speak some English.... very little....

Answer (score 1):

Your question - or actually the exact problem/error - is a bit unclear to me. Locating a form via FindComponent is a bit uncommon. At least you shouldn't call FindComponent more than nessecary, as it is potentially slow.

If you create a Form with WebApplication being the owner, it will be added to WebApplication.Forms
Web Application.FormCount is the number of forms (UserSession is a form in this context). WebApplication.ActiveForm is the form that is currently shown.